# Assign comboBox.ItemsSource from UserControl in another application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I built my own "search panel" in which I have a TextBox for the search term, 
a ComboBox to specify the search criterion and a Button to start the search.

ucSearchPanel XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestProjekt.Views.UserControls.ucSearchPanel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    Width="auto" Height="auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" >
            <Label Name="lblSearch" Width="{Binding ElementName=tbSearch, Path=ActualWidth}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">Suche</Label>
            <Label Name="lblSearchCriteria" Width="{Binding ElementName=cbSearchCriteria, Path=ActualWidth}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{Binding ElementName=lblSearch, Path=HorizontalContentAlignment}">Suchkriterium</Label>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox Name="tbSearch" MinWidth="100"></TextBox>
            <ComboBox Name="cbSearchCriteria" MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=tbSearch, Path=MinWidth}"  />
            <Button Name="btnSearch">Suche</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But the search criterions in the ComboBox vary from use case to use case... 
Therefore, I want to use the Property ItemsSource from the ComboBox in ucSearchPanel in different applications.

If I ssign the identifier  x: Name for ucSearchPanel, I can set ucSearchPanels.NameComboBox.ItemsSource via C# code in Code-Behind.

However, I want that to do in XAML, too. Therefore, I have created a Dependency Property:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

ucSearchPanel.xaml.cs:

  namespace TestProjekt.Views.UserControls
  {
      /// <summary>
      /// Interaktionslogik für ucSearchRegion.xaml
      /// </summary>
      public partial class ucSearchPanel : UserControl
      {
          public static readonly DependencyProperty cbSearchCriteriaItemsSourceProperty;
          public IEnumerable cbSearchCriteriaItemsSource
          {
              get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(cbSearchCriteriaItemsSourceProperty); }
              set { SetValue(cbSearchCriteriaItemsSourceProperty, value) }

          }

          public string cbDisplayMemberPath
          {
              get
              {
                  return cbSearchCriteria.DisplayMemberPath;
              }
              set
              {
                  cbSearchCriteria.DisplayMemberPath = value;
              }
          }

          static ucSearchPanel()
          {
              cbSearchCriteriaItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("cbSearchCriteriaItemsSource",
              typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ucSearchPanel));
          }

          public ucSearchPanel()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }
      }
  }
```

As you can see in the source code, I don't assign the Dependency Property to ComboBox.ItemsSource directly.
Thus, no items are displayed in my ComboBox in ucSearchPanel, if I bind an ObservableCollection to the Property.

I want to know how and where do I specify in C # code that the public static readonly DependencyProperty cbSearchCriteriaItemsSourceProperty refers to cbSearchCriteria.ItemsSource.

I want to thank you for your help in advance and remain

with best regards

Comment: You can specify a delegate in `DependencyProperty.Register()`

Comment: Hello Henk, thanks for your answer. But I don't know what do you mean. Could you give me an example, pkease?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem by adding the following lines of code in my constructor:

```
  Binding binding = new Binding("cbSearchPlaceItemsSource");
  binding.Source = this;
  cbSearchPlace.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

Now it works as I want it.